# How do you edit an element by index in a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, settext

How to set the text/name of a `JList` element in Java Swing?

I have created a list with 5 list elements.

When I do:

```
int currentIndex = list.getSelectedIndex();
```

I take the index of the current element.
I would like to edit/modify the Text of the current element index.
Is there any method for that?

e.g.

```
list.setText(CurrentIndex,"new text")
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html). It has the method [`setElementAt(E element, int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#setElementAt%28E,%20int%29) and [`add(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

- `setElementAt(E element, int index)` - Sets the component at the specified index of this list to be the specified element. The previous component at that position is discarded.
- `add(int index, E element)` - Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

---

You can initialize your `JList` with a `DefaultListModel` and then use all of the `DefaultListModel`s methods

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);
```

Then just use its methods

```
model.setElementAt("new text", index);
model.add(index, "new text");
```

---

**See:** [DefaultListModel javadoc for more methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#add%28int,%20E%29) | [How to use Lists tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 0):

//mouse click event

private void jListClientFileHeaderMappedMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:

```
    JList<String> theList = (JList) evt.getSource();
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) { //

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        int index = theList.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
        if (index >= 0) {

            final JList list = ((JList) (evt.getComponent()));
            if (list.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
                int i = list.getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println(list.getSelectedIndex());
                DefaultListModel<String> listModel = (DefaultListModel<String>) jListClientFileHeaderMapped.getModel();
                Object result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "value:");
                System.out.println(result);
                listModel.remove(i); //remove jlist item value 
                listModel.add(i, result.toString()); //add dialog text value

            }
        }
    }

}
```